# Regular/periodic pauses for unbuffered videos on mbpro / El Capitan

Tags: video, performance, youtube

Video is pausing/freezing up for approximately 250ms periodically every 1 to 1.5 seconds.  This behavior is occurring in Flash and youtube across almost all websites. An exception: Netflix is not affected due to its buffering of the fast incoming signal.

As shown in the screenshot I have excellent internet connectivity: >100mbps with 1ms latency.   These numbers were tested on both chrome and firefox.  Note: the speedtest itself was getting the *same pausing/freezing behavior* - even while reporting up to 110mbps!

[image]

The cpu level is low < 20% and there is free RAM available on my core i7 2.3GHz 16GB  retina display machine.

This behavior seems to briefly be mitigated after a fresh reboot: but soon continues again. Stopping/restarting the browsers (tried Chrome, safari, ff) has NO effect.  The behavior has been ongoing for weeks at the least.

Comment: What web browsers are you using?

Comment: @IronCraftMan  chrome, ff, safari  (updated OP)